# ajax request is not stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css-loader

Here is my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: "AutoRFQ_Vendors_ST.aspx/BindVesselGrid",
                        type: "POST",
                        timeout: 3000,
                        data: JSON.stringify(sendingdata),                  
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
    //do something
    }
```

Here is my CSS loader:

```
  ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
            ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
```

When I make an ajax call which responds `d:''` an empty string but my `ajaxstop:` event is not firing.

Comment: in the success method of ajax you can use jquery to remove css dynamically

Comment: I don't know... but shouldn't that be `$('body')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hide your loader on ajax() complete like:

```
ajax({
    complete: function(){
        $body.removeClass("loading");
    }
});
```

**complete** executes after either the success or error callback were executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the `ajaxStart` and the `ajaxStop` events falls under global event handlers in jQuery. Hence you need to hook them to `document` instead of having in your `$ajax` call.

You need to rewrite your code as,

```
$(document)
 .ajaxStart(function () {
   $body.addClass("loading");
 })
.ajaxStop(function () {
   $body.removeClass("loading");
});
```

Hope this helps!